# Showing equality of sequence of holomorphic functions to limit function if converges uniformly locally

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

I do not know how to proof following question:

Let $D$ be a domain in $C$.  ${{f}_{n}}$ be a sequence of holomorphic functions on $D$ that converges
uniformly locally to a function non-constant $f$. Show that for each $z\in D$,
there is a sequence ${{z}_{n}}\to z$ as ${{f}_{n}}({{z}_{n}})=f(z)$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

Actually, I know that I should use an assumption such as:
${{f}_{n}}({{z}_{n}})\ne f(z)$ 
Therefore, there is compact set    that 
$\left\| {{f}_{{{n}_{k}}}}({{z}_{{{n}_{k}}}})-f(z) \right\|>\varepsilon $ 
Then I think I have to use Montel theorem, but I do not know how to show the contradiction.

Comment: Welcome to MST, to be able to help you , it is preferable that you share us your own attempts to solve the question and where you are stuck.

Comment: Actually, I know that I should use an assumption such as:
${{f}_{n}}({{z}_{n}})\ne f(z)$ 
Therefore, there is compact set    that 
$\left\| {{f}_{{{n}_{k}}}}({{z}_{{{n}_{k}}}})-f(z) \right\|>\varepsilon $ 
Then I think I have to use Montel theorem, but I do not know how to show the contradiction.

Comment: I advise you to add this comment to your question.

Comment: Doesn't Uniform Convergence imply point wise convergence?

Comment: yes, Uni Con imply point wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $f$ is holomorphic in $D$, not constant, $f(z_0) = w_0$,
and $f_n \to f$ locally uniformly in $D$.

The zeros of $f - w_0$ are isolated, so there exists an $r > 0$ such that $B(z_0, r) \subset D$ and
$$
f(z) \ne w_0 \text{ for } 0 < |z - z_0| < r\, . \tag{*}
$$

Let $(\varepsilon_k)$ be a sequence such that
$0 < \varepsilon_k < r$ and $\varepsilon_k \to 0$.
It follows from $(*)$ that
$$
    m_k := \min_{z \in \partial B(z_0, \varepsilon_k)}  |f(z) - w_0|   > 0 \, .
$$
Since $f_n \to f$ uniformly on compact sets, there is an $n_k \in \mathbb N$
such that for all $z \in \partial B(z_0, \varepsilon_k)$
$$
   |(f_{n_k}(z) - w_0) - (f(z) - w_0)| = |f_{n_k}(z) - f(z)|  < m_k
   \le |f(z) - w_0| \, .
$$

Now [Rouché's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem)
implies that $f_{n_k} - w_0$ and $f - w_0$ have the same number of zeros
in $B(z_0, \varepsilon_k)$ (counting multiplicities).
In particular, there is (at least) one $z_{n_k} \in B(z_0, \varepsilon_k)$ such that $f_{n_k}(z_{n_k}) = w_0$.

This sequence $(z_{n_k})$ satisfies $z_{n_k} \to z_0$
and $f_{n_k}(z_{n_k}) = w_0 = f(z_0)$.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer

Comment: You can also use the uniform convergence with these estimate to find roots of $f_n(z)-w_0$ close to $z_0$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$, completing the task.